# Is Intellij IDEA auto compile and install jar into local repository?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

A weird phenomenon occurs when I am working with two projects:

`A` is an open source project I cloned from a git repo, `B` is my own project that dependents on `A`.

Since I modified some implementation in `A`, I build and install it into local repository with `mvn install`:

```
A-core_2.10-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
A-core_2.10-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-test.jar
....
```

But after a few days, when I found A behaves weird, I found many more jars occur in my local repository:

```
A-core_2.10-1.1.0-20150521.010136-4.jar
A-core_2.10-1.1.0-20150523.130616-22.jar
....
```

Does any one have any idea on what happens? 
Since I only `mvn install` once, where does the other jar `...-20150521.010136-r.jar` come from? Is it generated by Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an open source project and you didn't change the version number to a custom one, then this are most probably builds from the open source project itself. If there are newer snapshots available, Maven will download them, if you build your project B.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I don't quite understand what you mean by `this are most probably builds from the open source project itself`, I clone it to my local folder, imported into IDEA and only `mvn build` once in terminal since last modification, how did it accomplish that?

Comment: Well, if it's an open source project, then the project itself might have it's own build server, where they regularly build the libraries etc. (like for example the projects in the Apache foundation, Eclipse foundation etc.). What open source project did you clone?

Comment: I clone apache-spark, so you mean when I build my own project, which dependents on a `SNAPSHOT` version of Spark, maven would each time search the jar from build server and download the newest snapshot version automatically for me?

Comment: If so, can I stop maven to do this for me? should I set something in my pom? Since I really need my own version to use locally.

Comment: No, that's the whole usecase of Maven (and of Snapshots). If you want a customized version of Spark, then clone Spark, change the version number to something different (maybe add a String with your project name) and use that version.